# Property is a list of images c#

Tags: c#, image, list

I'm trying to have a property that is a list of images for my class named Album. So an album has a list of images. I tried understanding/following the documentation of system.windows.form for ImageList but to no success.

```
public class Album
{
   public ImageList photos { get; set; }
}
```

Like I'm not sure if imageList is what I am looking for I was trying to do something that would look like this:

```
public List<Image> photos { get; set; }
```

That is also available cross platform (works for Android & iOS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have answered your own question, this is what you should do:

```
public class Album
{
   public List<Image> photos { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't need to add/remove images like:

```
Album album = new Album();
album.photos.Add(anImage);
```

then you may even use Array of images like:

```
public class Album
{
   public Image[] photos { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is this code valid for android & iOS as this is for some cross-platform application?

Comment: you mean something like web service for android and ios?